# Prove $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$ is well-defined on $\ell ^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$1 \leq p < q \leq \infty$

$p=1$ and $q= \infty$

Let $(a_k)_{k \geq 1} \in \ell^1$, then $$\sum_{k \geq 1}|a_k|^1< \infty$$ (*) which means $\sup_{k \geq 1 } |a_k|^1 < \infty$. Hence it is well defined.

My lecturer said it is not enough to conclude after (*). Can someone help me fill the gap please.

Comment: The series converges thus $|a_k|\to 0$ thus bounded. Or what have you in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it is not always the case that "integrable implies bounded." For instance, for *functions* there exist unbounded functions $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ ($\dagger$).

But for series, we know that any convergent *series* must have a general term converging to $0$. The argument is simple: if the series with general term $a_n$ converges to some $\ell\in\mathbb{R}$, then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} \ell
$$
but then
$$
a_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} a_n \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} \ell-\ell = 0.
$$
So in this case, $(a_n)_n \in \ell_1(\mathbb{R})$ implies convergence to $0$, hence boundedness.

($\dagger$) The classic example being a piecewise-linear function made of sparsely spread triangular spikes with increasingly small basis but increasing height.

Comment: So in our case, it is that 
If $|a_k| \to 0$, then $|a_k|$ must be bounded.
  

If $|a_k|$ is bounded, then the $\sup|a_k|$ exists?? Is this it?

Comment: Yes. A converging sequence is bounded, and a bounded sequence (of real numbers) has a supremum.

Comment: Can I ask, would the proof of well defined be exactly the same for: $||.||_{\infty}$ well defined on $\ell^p$? But just write p instead of 1??

Comment: Yes, then it'll be basically the same. Another way to see it: if $(a_n)_n$ is in $\ell^p$, then $(\lvert a_n\rvert^{p} )_n$ is in $\ell^1$, and so by the argument above $(\lvert a_n\rvert^{p} )_n$ is bounded. This directly implies $(a_n)_n$ is bounded.